# Can you replicate AWS bundles from one region to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-workspaces

I have created AWS workspace bundles in us-east-1 and want to write a lambda that will monitor the bundles and replicate them in the us-west-2 region . Before I begin , is this possible to do ? is the AWS workspace an entity that I can copy?

Answer (score 0):

From: [Copy a Custom WorkSpaces Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/copy-custom-image.html)

> You can copy a custom WorkSpaces image within or across AWS Regions. Copying an image results in the creation of an identical image with its own unique identifier.

Then you can create a new bundle from this image in the new region.